# bx cf logs gives "Error dialing traffic controller server" when switching region

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I need a script to collect logs which must switch between regions via a `bx login -a`. I'm using the bluemix cli so that I can login using an apikey.

But when I switch regions the `bx cf logs app_name` goes haywire.

```
[Ops]$ bx cf logs AppName
Invoking 'cf logs AppName'...

FAILED
Error dialing traffic controller server: websocket: bad handshake.
Please ask your Cloud Foundry Operator to check the platform configuration (traffic controller is wss://doppler.eu-gb.bluemix.net:443).


[Ops]$ bx api
API endpoint: https://api.ng.bluemix.net (API version: 2.54.0)
```

See how my api is **ng** but the doppler is the UK's **eu-gb**.  If I run `cf logs` in UK region it does work fine.

Versions:

```
[Ops]$ bx --version
bx version 0.5.4+ae22935-2017-05-18T03:55:55+00:00

[Ops]$ bx update
Checking for updates...
No update required. Your CLI is already up-to-date.

[Ops]$ bx cf --version
Invoking 'cf --version'...

cf version 6.18.0+b22884b9c-2017-02-27
```

I found [this](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/886) and reckon at least related but note it's fixed in CF 6.26 and the embedded in bx version is 6.18.

Any workaround?  Logout/Login with -a doesn't help me.  I don't want to use cf directly due to my requirement to login via apikey.

Comment: I wrote a plugin to deal with doing stuff across multiple cf regions: https://github.com/data-henrik/cf-multi-instance Would that work for you?

Comment: @data_henrik, nice little thing but I don't think it'll help me here, I don't see how to get the logs from it. And it needs a the cf login which we're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluemix CLI embedded a CF CLI with version 6.18, 'bx app logs' actually invokes 'cf logs' as you can see from the messages. This embedded CF CLI needs to be upgraded.

A workaround is to just copy the cf cli binary to /usr/local/Bluemix/cfcli